# How to compute under-time using date time picker?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetimepicker

I have this code:

```
 Dim cmd3 As SqlCommand
 Dim rxd As SqlDataReader
 Dim nub As String = "select sum(case when datediff(minute, '09:00:00', [Time_In]) > 0 then datediff(minute, '09:00:00', [Time_In]) else 0 end) from timelogTB where EmpNo= @find and Date_ between @dtpFrom and @dtpTo "
        cmd3 = New SqlCommand(nub)
        cmd3.Connection = conn

        With cmd3
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@find", "EmpNo")
            .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@dtpFrom", dtpFrom.Value.ToString))
            .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@dtpTo", dtpTo.Value.ToString))
            .Parameters("@find").Value = Trim(comboxEmpno.Text)
        End With
        rxd = cmd3.ExecuteReader()

        If rxd.Read Then
            txtLate.Text = Trim(rxd.GetValue(0))
        End If
```

This code computes the tardiness of the employee. Can anyone give me hint on how to compute under-time of the employee. Let's say their time-in is before 9:00 am then their time-out is 6:00 pm. Then 1 employee time-out at 5:45 pm, how will I compute the 15 minutes as under-time of the employee. The record will be extracted from timelogTB where time-in and time-out columns are time data type while the date is date data type. I am using sql-server 2008. The time-in and time-out process is from form 1, in this form there is a time-in and time-out button to save the time. In form 2 I want to compute the under-time of an employee just like my question above.

[This image is the Time-in & Time-out window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJGgV.png)

[While the second image is the payments window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzKIO.png)

The codes that I first post is to compute the late of the employee, let's say if he/she enters 9:04 am the 4 minutes will be computed. So about under-time I believe just a minor modification will be sufficient.

Comment: is every employee set to work between 9.00 and 6.00? some sample data with your schema and expected output would be useful if there are other cases as otherwise you'll get an answer for this example but not one that covers every case.

Comment: Their working time is from 9am to 6pm. If an employee time-out before 6pm that's when the under-time will be computed.

Comment: can you add your table schema, columns and datatypes? for example, are you columns datatimes? As there's not enough information to provide an answer from what i can see.

Comment: The record will be extracted from timelogTB where time-in and time-out columns are time data type while the date is date data type. I am using sql-server 2008

Comment: Please add that info to the question by editing, it's important information. Comments aren't seen as important information so will often be missed.

Comment: The time-in and time-out process is from form 1, in this form there is a time-in and time-out button to save the time. In form 2 I want to compute the under-time of an employee just like my question above.

Comment: what if they start 10 minutes early and finish 10 minutes early? do you want them to be in for 9 hours or be in between 9 and 6?

Comment: It doesn't matter if starts 10 minutes early. i just want to compute if someone has under-time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should just store your In and Out time values as `DateTime` values and get rid of the date column, otherwise you have to join the 2 time values to the date field to do any date calculations. That just makes your code more complicated for no reason.

Your question is still a little unclear and I've done some basic calculations for you, so I'll post what I have in the hope that it helps you get to your final solution.

Run the below code in SQL Server, it uses a temporary table with dummy data, so it will not affect your data.

```
CREATE TABLE #timelogTB
    (
      EmpNo INT ,
      WorkDate DATE ,
      Time_In TIME ,
      Time_Out TIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #timelogTB
        ( EmpNo, WorkDate, Time_In, Time_Out )
VALUES  ( 1, '20170101', '09:00:00', '18:00:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170102', '09:00:00', '17:45:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170103', '09:00:00', '17:55:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170104', '08:50:00', '18:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170101', '09:00:00', '18:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170102', '09:00:00', '17:30:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170103', '09:00:00', '17:35:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170104', '09:00:00', '18:00:00' );

SELECT  * ,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                 CAST(CAST(WorkDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' '
                 + CAST(Time_In AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATETIME),
                 CAST(CAST(WorkDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' '
                 + CAST(Time_Out AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATETIME)) TotalMinutesWorked ,
        540 - DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                       CAST(CAST(WorkDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' '
                       + CAST(Time_In AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATETIME),
                       CAST(CAST(WorkDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' '
                       + CAST(Time_Out AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATETIME)) TotalMinutesShort
FROM    #timelogTB
WHERE   --EmpNo = 1 AND
        WorkDate BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170105';

DROP TABLE #timelogTB;
```

This code is checking the employees time in against 540 minutes (9 hours), which is the time between 9:00 - 18:00.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a common table expression

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #timelogTB
    (
      EmpNo INT ,
      WorkDate DATE ,
      Time_In TIME ,
      Time_Out TIME
    );

INSERT  INTO #timelogTB
        ( EmpNo, WorkDate, Time_In, Time_Out )
VALUES  ( 1, '20170101', '09:10:00', '18:00:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170102', '09:00:00', '17:45:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170103', '09:00:00', '17:55:00' ),
        ( 1, '20170104', '08:50:00', '18:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170101', '09:00:00', '18:00:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170102', '09:00:00', '17:30:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170103', '09:00:00', '17:35:00' ),
        ( 2, '20170104', '09:00:00', '18:00:00' );
```

**Query**

Query using CTE to calculate total time under per day by employee including an employee coming in late for work:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    Select EmpNo, WorkDate, DATEDIFF(minute, '09:00:00' , Time_In ) AS TimeUnder
    from #timelogTB
    WHERE TIME_IN > '09:00:00'
    UNION 
    Select EmpNo, WorkDate, DATEDIFF(minute, Time_Out, '18:00:00') AS TimeUnder
    from #timelogTB
    WHERE TIME_OUT < '18:00:00'
)
SELECT EmpNo, WorkDate, Sum(TimeUnder) As TimeUnder
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY EmpNo, WorkDate
```

**Results**

```
EmpNo   WorkDate    TimeUnder
1       2017-01-01  10
1       2017-01-02  15
2       2017-01-02  30
1       2017-01-03  5
2       2017-01-03  25
```

Comment: Sir what is CTE stands for?

Comment: @AtanHokage04 see first line of answer:- common table expression. See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx